# Como puedo usar useState hook en un bucle infinito?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, usestate, hook

Soy principiante en React y quiero crear un componente que este en constante movimiento, incrementando su estilo de translate, pero el incremento no se comporta como lo esperaria, que esta pasando?

Este es mi componente:

```
`function Point() {

  const [countX, setCountX] = useState(0);
  const [countY, setCountY] = useState(0);

  setInterval(() => {
    setCountX((count) => count + 1);
    setCountY((count) => count + 1);

    console.log(countX+":"+countY);

  }, 500);

  const styles = {
    transform: `translate(${countX}px,${countY}px)`,
  };

  return <PointStyle style={styles} />;
}
`
```

y la salida por consola es la siguiente:

0:0 1:1 0:0 2:2 1:1 4:4 0:0 5:5 2:2 7:7 1:1 9:9 4:4 10:10 11:11 0:0 12:12 5:5 14:14 2:2 7:7

De antemano gracias por la ayuda

Answer (score 1):

Esa clase de cosas, `setInterval` o `setTimeouts` o ese tipo de web API's deberían ser usadas dentro de useEffect, debemos de limpiar el interval usando `clearInterval` y mandandole nuestro interval a `clearInterval`, el hacer un console log no te mostrará bien el update del estado, pues el `setInterval` corre de una manera distinta que el hook `useEffect`, para poder ver el update sería mejor renderizar la variable, algo así:

```js
const {useState,useEffect} = React

function Point(props) {

  const [countX, setCountX] = useState(0);
  const [countY, setCountY] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
  const interval = setInterval(() => {
    setCountX(countX => countX + 1);
    setCountY(countY => countY + 1);
  }, 1000);
  return () => clearInterval(interval);
}, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <h2>{countX}</h2>
      <h2>{countY}</h2>
    </div>
  );
}

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render( <Point />)
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: He creado un snippet con tu código para poder ejecutarlo directamente y he añadido algo de formato a la respuesta, espero que no te moleste :)